# From Nginx subpath to root in different port

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have one server with several web services exposed in different ports in docker containers.

With nginx I would like use subpaths to browse througth these servers.
For example: 
I have Nextcloud in http://myurl:8080/
Reachable from http://myurl:80/nextcloud.

I tried different solution, probably the most closed to reach the solution is the following:

```
 location /nextcloud/{

    proxy_pass http://myurl:8080/;
    }
```

But in this way I lost the first parameter in the url:
instead of proxying on http://myurl/nextcloud/a/b; I'm proxed on http://myurl/nextcloud/b, losing /a

Answer (score 0):

```
location /nagios/ {
    rewrite ^/nagios(/.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass  http://10.0.21.8:80/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect    off;
}
```

Reference: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/NGINX_proxy_folder_to_different_root.html